# Reinstating the correct extension on image files where the extension was removed

Tags: bash

I have 30k+ images without extensions...

I used a program called GPRename to give each of my images a random name, because some of the names were very long so they were causing problems, and it deleted the file extension on all my pictures. Now I'm having difficulty opening the images on my Windows computer and my phone (no prob on Linux)

I was wondering if any of you know of a program/script I can use that would add the correct file extension to the end of all the images?
I was thinking of a script using the bash command "file" but I'm not very good with Bash so I would have no idea how to do this for multiple files.

The file extensions include .jpg  .png  .gif  .webm:

```
ssd006: JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.01
ssdss078: PNG image data, 1920 x 1080, 8-bit/color RGB, non-interlaced
ssdss029: GIF image data, version 89a, 300 x 168
ssds008:  WebM
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**NOTE:** I can't test this code, so for safety's sake, this currently just *prints out* the commands that it would run.  To actually run them, delete the `echo`:

```
mkdir ../new
for f in *; do
    case `file "$f"` in
    *JPEG*) e=jpg ;;
    *GIF*) e=gif ;;
    *PNG*) e=png ;;
    *WebM*) e=webm ;;
    *) e=UNKNOWN ;;
    esac
    echo mv "$f" "../new/$f.$e"
done
```

Any files that it doesn't recognise will get an extension of `.UNKNOWN`.

Comment: Would this work if not all the files are .jpg?   Some are .png  a few .gif and a few .webm    are in there as well i believe

Comment: No.  I'd assumed all your pictures were the same type!

Comment: OK, I don't have access to a terminal at the moment, but if you can write in a comment the output of the `file` command on an example of each file type, I should be able to cook something up...

Comment: an example ***of each file type***

Comment: XD srry I hadn't meant to send that yet

Comment: ssd006: JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.01
ssdss078: PNG image data, 1920 x 1080, 8-bit/color RGB, non-interlaced
ssdss029: GIF image data, version 89a, 300 x 168
ssds008:  WebM

Comment: not sure if i'm just not using this right or what but it's not working it gives me the output saying it moved file *** to ../new/***.*  but when i look in "new" the folder is empty

Comment: that would explain it... well now it works perfect thank you!!

Comment: @SanMadJack: Glad to hear it :)