# Moving groups of files into sub-directories

Tags: linux, bash, debian

I have 30k+ images and many folders that hold these images.  What I would like is to have 100 images per folder. Does anyone know of a Linux program/script that could help me with this?

Preferably I would like the program/script to be able to create directories (i.e. images-001, images-002, images-003, etc) and then place 100 images (varying extensions .gif .jpg .png .bmp .webm) in each folder.

Comment: How are you planning on partitioning the files into the folders? Randomly? By name? By type? By directory entry order?

Comment: Randomly all I realy want is 100 files per folder so it's easier to manage.

Comment: 100 random files per folder doesn't sound easy to manage since you'll never be able to find anything... without an external indexing mechanism of some sort. But if that's what you really want `xargs` will likely be of help.

Comment: I strongly recommend you make a backup of the original files before you start this mass renaming.  There is too much risk of you repenting of what you did.

Comment: Related, by the same questioner, but different: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26171286.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use standard and more controllable commands for better organized files:

```
cd <your_image_folder_pathname>    
mkdir img_jpg img_gif img_bmp img_tiff

mv *.jpg img_jpg
mv *.gif img_gif
mv *.bmp img_bmp
mv *.tiff img_tiff
```

Move remaining files to img_misc

```
mkdir img_misc
find -type f | xargs -I {} mv {} img_misc
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Linux, the GNU `mv` command has a convenient option `-t target-directory` which can be useful with `xargs`, but here we need to create a different target directory every 100 files, so we won't be using `-t`.

The `xargs` command can group file names into sets of 100.  The residual issue is determining the directory name for the target.  For that, a shell script is appropriate:

```
#!/bin/bash

mkdir -p images-000
dirnum=$(ls -d images-[0-9][0-9][0-9] | sed -n '$s/images-//p')
newdir="images-$(($dirnum + 1))"
mv "$@" "$newdir"  # or: qmv -t "$newdir" "$@"
rm -fr images-000
```

The `images-000` directory is created to initialize things but is never a target for any files.  It is OK to parse `ls` this time because the names it lists will contain no spaces, newlines or other awkward characters.  (In general, be extremely cautious about parsing the output of `ls`.)

With that script called `move-files.sh`, you can now run something like:

```
find /source/place-1 /opt/photos/place-2 … -type f -print0 |
xargs -0 -n 100 -r -- movefiles.sh
```

Note that `-print0` and `-0` are primarily GNU extensions for `find` and `xargs`, but Mac OS X `find` and `xargs` also support them.  The `-r` option to `xargs` is also a GNU extension; it is not supported by Mac OS X `xargs` and it has no equivalent.  It is also known as `--no-run-if-empty`; it means that `xargs` does not run the program `movefiles.sh` if there are no file names listed, unlike standard `xargs` which is required to run the command at least once even with no file nams.  If you don't have `-r`, you can revise the script with `if [ $# != 0 ]; then …current script…; fi` to protect it if it is called with zero arguments.